# Is there a way to perform a VLookup or similar function that will return the last but one value?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have the following dataset on which I am trying to return enter a value in ColD which is the QTY for  the last entry of a given reference (ColB).  The way I have attempted to approach it was to use Index & Filter
e.g. =index(FILTER($B$1:$D,$B$1:B=B5),E5,3)
and I was hoping I might be able to create a row count that was iterative which I could use within the Index/Filter formula (replacing E5 in the above example) but I just can't seem to make that work.

I could of course be approaching this all wrong and there may be another way of approaching it.  Ideally the resulting formula would be an arrayformula as the table will grow week on week.

/clunky explaination.

[Here is a link to an example sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eIncv3V2gjkpzgqwKKA6cZLTFBi8PGj2tAF9TA2gop0/edit#gid=0)

[Pic My dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqu0t.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I duplicated the sheet and then entered in E1

```
={"COUNT"; ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B2:B), COUNTIFS(B2:B, B2:B, ROW(B2:B), "<="&ROW(B2:B)),))}
```

and in F1

```
={"LAST VALUE"; ArrayFormula(if(E2:E<2,,VLOOKUP(B2:B&(E2:E-1), {B2:B&E2:E,C2:C}, 2, 0 )))}
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: That worked brilliantly - thank you JPV.  Can't tell you how many hours this week i've gotten close to.

Comment: Hi @MorrisCoyle: Glad to hear it worked. See here to learn how to accept an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Have a great day !